# What is the equivalence of Type Name Handling with encoding/json in Go?

Tags: go, polymorphism, marshalling

### Short Description in Prose

I have a situation where I want to unmarshal JSON data into an array of structs (either `Foo` or `Bar` and many more) that all implement a common interface `MyInterface`. Also all of the eligble struct types that implement the interface have a common field which I named `Discrimininator` in the example below.
The Discriminator¹ allows to bi-uniquely find the correct struct type for each value of Discriminator.

#### The Problem and Error Message

But during unmarshling the code does not "know" which is the correct "target" type. The unmarshaling fails.

> cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type main.MyInterface

### MWE in

https://play.golang.org/p/Dw1hSgUezLH

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type MyInterface interface {
    // some other business logic methods go here!
    GetDiscriminator() string // GetDiscriminator returns something like a key that is unique per struct type implementing the interface
}

type BaseStruct struct {
    Discriminator string // will always be "Foo" for all Foos, will always be "Bar" for all Bars
}

type Foo struct {
    BaseStruct
    // actual fields of the struct don't matter. it's just important that they're different from Bar
    FooField string
}

func (foo *Foo) GetDiscriminator() string {
    return foo.Discriminator
}

type Bar struct {
    BaseStruct
    // actual fields of the struct don't matter. it's just important that they're different from Foo
    BarField int
}

func (bar *Bar) GetDiscriminator() string {
    return bar.Discriminator
}

// Foo and Bar both implement the interface.
// Foo and Bars are always distinguishible if we check the value of Discriminator

func main() {
    list := []MyInterface{
        &Bar{
            BaseStruct: BaseStruct{Discriminator: "Bar"},
            BarField:   42,
        },
        &Foo{
            BaseStruct: BaseStruct{Discriminator: "Foo"},
            FooField:   "hello",
        },
    }
    jsonBytes, _ := json.Marshal(list)
    jsonString := string(jsonBytes)
    fmt.Println(jsonString)
    // [{"Discriminator":"Bar","BarField":42},{"Discriminator":"Foo","FooField":"hello"}]
    var unmarshaledList []MyInterface
    err := json.Unmarshal(jsonBytes, &unmarshaledList)
    if err != nil {
        // Unmarshaling failed: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type main.MyInterface
        fmt.Printf("Unmarshaling failed: %v", err)
    }
}
```

### In other languages

#### TypeNameHandling as known from .NET

In Newtonsoft, a popular .NET JSON Framework, this is solved by a something called "[TypeNameHandling](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_TypeNameHandling.htm)" or can be solved with a custom JsonConverter . The framework will add something like a magic `"$type"` key on root level to the serialized/marshaled JSON which is then used to determine the original type on deserialization/unmarshaling.

#### Polymorphism in ORMs

¹A similar situation occurs under the term "polymorphism" in ORMs when instances of multiple types having the same base are saved in the same table. One typically introduces a discriminator column, hence the name in above example.

Comment: There is no inheritance in Go, only embedding. Go does not have an equivalent to what you are describing in .NET.

Comment: @Adrian ok, and how would you handle such a situation in Go?

Comment: I'd start from the need/goal and rethink the entire approach to use Go idioms, rather than attempting to use .NET idioms in Go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can implement a custom [`json.Unmarshaler`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json@go1.17.1#Unmarshaler). For that you'll need to use a named slice type instead of the unnamed `[]MyInterface`.

Within the custom unmarshaler implementation you can unmarshal the JSON array into a slice where each element of the slice is a [`json.RawMessage`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json@go1.17.1#RawMessage) representing the corresponding JSON object. After that you can iterate over the slice of raw messages. In the loop unmarshal from each raw message only the `Discriminator` field, then use the `Discriminator` field's value to determine what the correct type is into which the full raw message can be unmarshaled, finally unmarshal the full message and add the result to the receiver.

```golang
type MyInterfaceSlice []MyInterface

func (s *MyInterfaceSlice) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    array := []json.RawMessage{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &array); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    *s = make(MyInterfaceSlice, len(array))
    for i := range array {
        base := BaseStruct{}
        data := []byte(array[i])
        if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &base); err != nil {
            return err
        }

        var elem MyInterface
        switch base.Discriminator {
        case "Foo":
            elem = new(Foo)
        case "Bar":
            elem = new(Bar)
        }
        if elem == nil {
            panic("whoops")
        }

        if err := json.Unmarshal(data, elem); err != nil {
            return err
        }
        (*s)[i] = elem
    }
    return nil
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/mXiZrF392aV

Comment: Maybe return an `error` instead of `panic` in the event of a non-compliant type.